# how to distinquish between live ips among several ips

Tags: network-programming, ip

In a project i was made to list a number of live ips among many ips, how do I do it?

Nmap scan report for 196.43.196.9
Host is up (0.00016s latency).
Nmap scan report for 196.43.196.10
Host is up (1.1s latency).
Nmap scan report for ns1.aiti-kace.com.gh (196.43.196.11)
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Nmap scan report for ns2.aiti-kace.com.gh (196.43.196.12)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Nmap scan report for 196.43.196.13
Host is up (0.00029s latency).
Nmap scan report for 196.43.196.14
Host is up (0.0017s latency).
Nmap scan report for mail.aiti-kace.com.gh (196.43.196.15)
Host is up (0.033s latency).
Nmap scan report for 196.43.196.16
Host is up (0.00097s latency).

nmap 196.43.196.24